# Turn a mains AC load off when another one is ON

Tags: switches, ac, mains

What would be a way to turn OFF load A (10 amps) as soon as load B (10 amps as well) is turned ON, faster than the time it takes for a circuit breaker to trip (~15 ms)? 
Something like a voltage activated switch or relay?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33700/how-to-make-on-off-switch-for-popcorn-maker

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69984/turning-off-the-grill-when-the-espresso-maker-is-on

Answer (score 1):

If you are the one who has control over turning off load A, then a relay is a good way to do it. A DPDT relay with load A on the normally closed toggle and load B on the normally open toggle would work quite nicely. Load B would be turned on at the same instant load A is turned off, when your relay is activated.

Comment: Thanks, but... I don't have 'control' over load A. Load A is supposed to be ON all the time, and turn OFF only when load B is manually turned ON...the point of this is to never exceed 10 amps at any given time on the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve a changeover with a SPDT **BREAK BEFORE MAKE** relay if the neutral is common to both loads.

[image]

Load A is connected to the normally closed connection of the relay. Only when a switch is operated will the relay be powered and switch over to load B. By using a break before make relay the loads will never be connected at the same time.
For a more sophisticated system you could replace the switch operating the relay with any appropriate electronic version. You may even like to consider a zero-crossing circuit so that the relay is operated when the load current is minimum.